# static library generated by gcc makefile is empty, why?

Tags: makefile, static-libraries, .a

I'm trying to create a simple static library "mylib.a" using  makefile and gcc.
The object files are created in the source directories,the library "mylib.a"  is also created but it is empty (but the file shows some of kb). This is my makefile:

```
CPPUTEST_HOME = C:\UTest
CPP_PLATFORM = Gcc

TARGET= mylib.a

CPP    = g++
FLAGS        = -std=gnu99 -Iinclude
CFLAGS       = -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -march=native -ggdb3
DEBUGFLAGS   = -O0 -D _DEBUG
RELEASEFLAGS = -O2 -D NDEBUG -combine -fwhole-program
LDFLAGS = -shared  # linking flags

SOURCES = \
    $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/CppUTest/file1.cpp \
    $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/CppUTest/file2.cpp \
    $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/CppUTest/file3.cpp \
    $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/CppUTest/file4 

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CPP) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(TARGET)       $(OBJECTS)

  clean:
  rm $(OBJECTS)
```

What is wrong on this? I m also a newby regarding makefiles...

Comment: "it is empty (but the file shows some of kb)" - which is it? Is `mylib.a` empty or not?

Comment: What output do you get when you run `make`?

Comment: Are you sure you are doing what you think you are doing? `g++` isn't generally how people create static library/archives.

Comment: As Etan says, you can't create a static library with a compiler.  You're creating a program executable, named `mylib.a`.  Also, you appear to be running on Windows which has its own idiosyncracies but you should absolutely not use backslashes in your pathnames: only forward slashes.

Comment: Hi  MadScientist, ok thank you for the hints, you are right, maybe I'm on the "wrong way". I will take a better look into the gnu gcc manual.

Comment: If you're using UNIX-style tools, you create static libraries using the "ar" (archive) tool not the compiler.  You create executables and shared libraries using the compiler.  However I'm not familiar with Windows tools or even with GCC running on Windows, so things might be different there I suppose.

Comment: Oh, problem is solved. I misunderstand some things regarding the pure creation of a library and linking the created library.

Answer (score 0):

So, as result I get: 
    $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/CppUTest/file1.o , 
    $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/CppUTest/file2.o, 
    $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/CppUTest/file3.o, 
    $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/src/CppUTest/file4.o,

and on top of the directory 
    ((CPPUTEST_HOME)/src)) 
I get the "mylib.a" file. This lib is empty. But if I look into the properties, the "mylib.a" file has about 60kb....

Comment: Why do you say the file is empty?  What are you using to say it's empty, vs. the properties of the file?

Comment: I meant, when i open the archive "mylib.a", there are no object files inside, nothing is inside, but when i right click on  "mylib.a" --> properties, I see the the size of "mylib.a" is about 60kb

Comment: That's because it's not an archive.  I don't know how you're trying to "open the archive", but you won't find any archived objects in it.